# Creating Python Tkinter exe file with Pyinstaller problem

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have created GUI python2.7 program with Tkinter successfully without error. Now I want to make an executable file of it using pyinstaller in anaconda environment (I'm using windows 10).

Using this command 
`pyinstaller --onefile main.py` I am able to create exe file successfully in dist folder. But when I tried to run the exe file, it showed error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "main.py", line 333, in <module>   
File "main.py", line 90, in __init__   
File "lib-tk\ttk.py", line 715, in current
_tkinter.TclError: Index 0 out of range 
[22668] Failed to execute script main
```

Is the problem related to tkinter? I've tried the solution here : [Problems with Pyinstaller with tkinter app on python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528665/problems-with-pyinstaller-with-tkinter-app-on-python-3-5) and here : [How to make pyinstaller import the ttk theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380748/how-to-make-pyinstaller-import-the-ttk-theme) . But still same error

Comment: I would use cx_freeze to compile an exe. I have made a few projects with that library instead of pyinstaller.

Comment: Use Py-Auto-Gui for this

Answer (score 1):

Try and do:

> pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py

The -w flag stops python from bringing up the console, and so this could be why tkinter is failing.

Source:
[This cool video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&t=318s)

I highly recommend you watch this video as it also goes a little in depth on how to clean up after building the exe.

Comment: Just realized this was posted a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I used [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) to create single exe file for a [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) project, which contained several py files:

Main.py is my main python file which calls tkinter UI and I had several other python files imported to this Main.py.
Some libraries which I used include pandas,pyodbc

Open cmd in the same directory of the project; Use following command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon=XYZ.ico "C:/Users/.../Tkinter_Project/Main.py"
```

Application was created with no dependencies. If there is any config or image files used, simply copy paste it to the 'dist' folder which gets created.